# Query Open FDA for application_number, ndc, and rxcui

Tags: api, openfda

My apologies if this has been asked: I am new to using OpenFDA and am trying to query the database to obtain a list of the ndc and rxcui associated with a particular application numbers appearing in FAERS. More specifically, I downloaded faers and tried to query one of the application numbers appearing in the dataset, e.g. 21752. However, I obtained the error "no matches found" when searching for on a specific applications number, e.g. https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=20patient.drug.openfda.application_number:"2221752".

Is it possible to query openFDA event data to obtain the ndc and rxcui associated with a specific application number?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Jack with the openFDA team. It is certainly possible to search by application number, but yhe format of the number in your example seems off. Typically the application numbers are either `ANDA######` or `NDA######`. See example below.
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.application_number:ANDA076407